# A more efficient version of jQuery contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following JavaScript and jQuery, which works perfectly:

```
function updateTaskTypes(taskTypes) {

    $.each(taskTypes, function (idx, e) {

        var contains = $("#async_TaskTypes").find("a:contains('" + e + "')").length > 0;

        if (!contains) {

            var html = "<li><a href=\"#tab" + idx + "\">" + e + "</a></li>";

            $("#async_TaskTypes").append(html);
        }
    });
}
```

The above code takes an array of strings. The aim is to add an `<li>` to `#async_TaskTypes` if it doesn't already contain one.

The format of the HTML is:

```
<ul id="async_TaskTypes" class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab0">Preview Blog Comment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab1">Respond To Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

My problem is the jQuery doesn't seem as efficient as it could be. Is there a way to make the above code more efficient?

By 'efficient', I mean perhaps there is a more direct jQuery function I could use, or a cleaner algorithm etc... Basically more elegant code.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean with "efficient". More memory-efficient? More cpu-efficient? Or more elegant code?

Comment: Why don't you add an ID for task types to the li's instead of searching the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search in the DOM is always inefficient. You should have a model where you store which tasks are already on the shown list, so that you can simply search trough that with array methods (and if sorted, even possible in `O(n)`). This could do it, for example:

```
function updateTaskTypes(taskTypes) {
    var $ul = $("#async_TaskTypes"),
        texts = $ul.find("a").map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
    $.each(taskTypes, function (idx, e) {
        if ($.inArray(texts, e) == -1)
            $ul.append("<li><a href=\"#tab" + idx + "\">" + e + "</a></li>");
    });
}
```

Or you just remove all list items and reappend the whole task list, which is much simpler and might be even faster for short lists:

```
function updateTaskTypes(taskTypes) {
    var $ul = $("#async_TaskTypes").empty();
    $.each(taskTypes, function (idx, e) {
        $ul.append("<li><a href=\"#tab" + idx + "\">" + e + "</a></li>");
    });
}
```

Comment: This is good if you want the list always to reflect the order of `taskTypes` (or some custom sort thereof). If however you wanted newly introduced items always to appear at the end of the list (and a custom sort could not do the job), then a different approach is required (eg as in the question, or by maintaining an appropriately-keyed js object of booleans and using it for lookup).

Comment: @Beetroot: Exactly. I expected this since the index in the array is used as an identifier, but for the other possibility I've added a script as well (not with a fancy hashmap, though :-)

Comment: There are so many variations on this one, the OP's problem is too much choice!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can actually just use a regular expression:

```
var a = $("#async_TaskTypes").html();
if( /Whatever/g.test(a) ) {
  //this string is present in your html
}
```

Comment: That would be really slow I think.

Comment: @Sylvanus: Why? The DOM is only queried once, and regex is fast. Only it might not be as reliable as `contains`, which looks through the `text()` of the single elements.

Comment: Because it searches through the whole inner text of the #async_TaskTypes, nost just the <a> elements.

Comment: @Sylvanus: Yet there's not much text outside the `<a>` elements, is it? And of course, you could narrow it down to `$.map($("#async_TaskTypes a"), function(){return $(this).text();}).join("\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Updating Bergi's answer:

```
function updateTaskTypes(taskTypes) {
    var $ul = $("#async_TaskTypes").empty();
    $.each(taskTypes, function (idx, e) { 
        $ul.append(
            $("<li>").append(
                $("<href>", {id: "tab" + idx}).text(e)
            );
        );
    });
}
```

Maybe a little bit more elegant.

Comment: If you're doing it that way, you should use `.text()` instead of `.html()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:

```
var async_TaskTypes = $("#async_TaskTypes");
async_TaskTypes.append(
    $.map(taskTypes, function (idx, e) {
        if (!async_TaskTypes.has("a:contains('" + e + "')")) {
            return $("<li>").append(
                $("<href>", {id: "tab" + idx}).text(e)
            );
        }
    })
);
```